# Consquences of recreating Access Service Application

Tags: access-services

I am trying to debug this and am looking for some help.

This is a SP 2010 farm and here is the error which comes up every few seconds.

```
There was an error in communicating with Access Database Service http://myappserver/eb2cd6f555a946a5abdd0bbe20b1c31a/AccessService.svc exception: The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable. [Session:  User: corp\apppool].
```

I noticed that the app pool in IIS was stopped so I started it but it soon crashes yielding 503 error.

If I drop and recreate this service what are the consequences if users have already used it?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that the service account has a expired password?

Test the service application with a new service account and see if you get the same results.

Comment: I ran $access = Get-SPAccessServiceApplication; $access.ApplicationPool;  The account in the ProcessAccountName property is not locked

Comment: And did you try with another service account? If you get the same error with a different service account then we can rule out any problems with the application pool and look at the service application.

Comment: Access Services is listed under SharePoint Web Services Default which contains many other service apps which appear to be working fine. Assume the existing service app acct is fine, What can we examine on the Service App Specifically without drop/recreate?

Comment: As the applicationpool tries to start itselft in IIS but fails it should leave a trace in the logs. Have you looked at the Security event logs when you try to access the http://myappserver/eb2cd6f555a946a5abdd0bbe20b1c31a/AccessService.svc path after you restart the application pool? I would like to test a iisreset/reboot/sharepoint config flush but I would never do that on a production environment without proper planning and maintinance windows. I have tried to reproduce your proplem on my system but I only get close to 503 when my svc account password is wrong.